# Flixel vs. Flashpunk

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have written basic physics into a lander type game with randomly generated tile based terrain. Seeing as I will be getting a screenshot question, I will attach one.

[image: screenshot with artifacts]

I still have artifacts, but that is besides the point, they have to do with identifying tiles and displaying the right tile. I have a very simple custom physics implementation using vectors.

I have recently read up on Flixel and Flashpunk. I am interested in using one of them for this project and the other for the next project I am going to do. I want to learn box2d and know that Flashpunk would be better suited for this, as it does not have a physics implementation from what I have been reading. Flixel does have its own implementation.

The following link lists a few differences between the two and benefits of both...
http://matttuttle.com/2011/02/flixel-vs-flashpunk/

Although his major grip with pixel perfect collision can be fixed with these extensions to Flixel, demo on the page...
http://www.photonstorm.com/flixel-power-tools

I am leaning towards doing Flixel for this project, as the biggest thing I want to learn from this project has to do with the tilebased random terrain generation. Both Flixel and Flashpunk provide some sort of support for this.

I am thinking of leaving Flashpunk for a more physically based project and include box2D there. My question is this... given the above, which framework is more suited for what tasks, or do they both accomplish the same thing? Which one then does it better?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. There is no definitive answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask
Maybe post this on some other site?

Comment: try to ask at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, actually you can migrate your question there (flag it for moderator attention and a comment that you want to migrate it)

Comment: We'll be happy to migrate this if the OP flags for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenters stated there is no definite answer. It sounds like you already answered the question yourself when you stated 'I want to learn Box2D, and FlashPunk would be better suited for this". I have been working with FlashPunk for over a year now on hobby games and love it. However, as for my answer to your question, I usually suggest to developers who are just starting out to try out both Flixel and FlashPunk and stick to the one they are most comfortable with.

Lastly, both engines are capable of handling what you want to accomplish (assuming you add a physics engine to FlashPunk). There are many posts on the flashpunk.net forums explaining how to do so.